# Auto form submission in cakephp page

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I want to auto submit form in cakephp ctp file. Can anyone please help me? I know there are number of same or similar question have asked before this. It tried everything, but it doesn't work. Please have a look on my code:

SCRIPT PART:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
        alert("reached here");
        document.frmTransaction.submit();
    }
</script>
```

HTML PART:

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/sale/pay" name="frmTransaction" id="frmTransaction" onSubmit="return validate()" onLoad="javascript:autoSubmit();">
    <input name="account_id" type="hidden" value="<?echo $_POST['account_id'] ?>" />
    <input name="return_url" type="hidden" size="60" value="<?echo $_POST['return_url'] ?>" />
    <input name="mode" type="hidden" size="60" value="<? echo $_POST['mode']?>" />
    <table style="width:50%">
        <tr>
            <td>Reference:&nbsp;</td><td><input name="reference_no" type="text" value="<? echo $_POST['data']['reference_no'] ?>" readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount:&nbsp;</td><td><input name="amount" type="text" value="<? echo $_POST['data']['amount'] ?>"  readonly/>Rs.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="description" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['description'] ?>" />

    <input name="name" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['name'] ?>" />
    <input name="email" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['email'] ?>" />
    <input name="phone" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['phone'] ?>" />
    <input name="address" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['address'] ?>" />
    <input name="country" type="hidden" value="IND" />
    <input name="postal_code" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['postal'] ?>" />
    <input name="state" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['state'] ?>" />
    <input name="city" type="hidden" value="<? echo $_POST['city'] ?>" />

    <input name="secure_hash" type="hidden" size="60" value="<? echo $secure_hash;?>" />
    <br/><br/><br/><input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" style="background:#ff6600;color:#fff;height:40px;width:150px;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 22px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cakephp, autosubmitting is on the client side.

Comment: I know, but similar code is working in general html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check form definition again.

Remove onload event statement.

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/sale/pay" name="frmTransaction" id="frmTransaction" onSubmit="return validate()">
```

Comment: Although I have solved this error, but anyway thanks for suggestion.